# Center child of Container with BoxShape.circle

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build a custom add and minus button like in this image:
[image: Row of Buttons]

I have written this code (don't mind the colors):

```
Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
             ),
            ),
```

which results in this button: [image]

**How can I center the Icon? Why is the Center widget not working?**

Comment: Because the IconButton has a default margin or padding, and the Container outside it just not big enough to fit in it. If you increase the Container's size, you will find it can center it correctly now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `IconButton`'s size.

Consider using like this

```
 Container(
          height: 30,
          width: 30,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

try with Fitted box

```
Container(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 30,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: const FittedBox(
                        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                        child: Icon(Icons.add),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
```

output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply set padding to zero and empty constraints in iconbutton. The reason for shift is that padding and constraints of the icon are bigger then the size of circular container.

```
Container(
              height: 30,
              width: 30,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: IconButton(
                padding:EdgeInsets.zero,
                constraints:BoxConstraints(),
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.black,
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
             ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try by increasing the height and removing the width this!

```
 Container(
            height: 40,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              color: Colors.black,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
```